# Cookies getting deleted after closing browser?

Tags: javascript

Although i have written code for setting an expiry date for cookie but cookie gets deleted after closing browser.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) { 
if (days) {  
var date = new Date(); 
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();} 
else var expires = ""; 
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

}
```

i want to set for 30 days

```
createCookie('count',count,30);
```

Comment: If your browser's settings or add-in only allow session cookies your cookie will be deleted on closing.

Comment: @Alina can you help me,what should i set in browser's settings???thanks

Comment: In my browser, option selected is Allow local data to be set..